# Why if not getting the value of input? "Python"

Tags: if-statement, input, printing

as you can see down it's not giving the value of input to the if! why? and how i can make the value of input be stored to Variable (number)

```
number = input(f"Enter a Number? ")
if number == (1):
    print("one")
if number == (2):
    print("two or greater")
else:
    print("negative number")
```

```
Enter a Number? 1
negative number
```

Comment: what language is  this? Please edit labels.

Comment: it's Python. and i edit it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some issues, usually when you use `input` and expect a number to be submitted, you want to use `int()` before it to make sure the input is understood as a number (type int). Furthemore, when you want to state an "else-if" statement you should use `elif`. Finally, the parenthesis are not necessary in your `if` statement. The following should work:

```
number = int(input("Enter a Number? "))
if number == 1:
    print("one")
elif number >= 2: #I've changed this syntax, because two or greater is written like this
    print("two or greater")
else:
    print("negative number")
```

Here is the output I'm trying:

```
Enter a Number? 3
two or greater
```

Comment: When i enter 1 as a number it's print one and a negative number!                        On the on the other hand when i enter a 2 it's print two or greater only so why i'm getting negative number on 1

Comment: Did you copy-paste my syntax? It returns `one` to me! Also, careful that 0 will return `negative number`